# How does Authenticator gets the PMK which is used to calculate PTK?

Tags: authentication, key-management, radius, wpa2-eap, handshake

I am trying to setup a Supplicant- authenticator and AAA server to perform EAPOL mechanism.

I am able to successfully completed the EAP authentication procedure but 4-way handshake was not initiated by Authenticator. I have 2 questions here.

1. How does authenticator know that it needs to perform 4-way handshake after successful EAP authentication.
2. How will Autheticator gets the PMK from RADIUS server. As the PMK/MSK is generated by both supplicant and RADIUS server separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Master Key is passed in the Access-Accept message itself. RADIUS decoder for wireshark says it as Vendor specific attribute so I was not able to identify it initially.
Below RFC links explains in more detail about the Vendor specific attributes key passed during Access-Accept message.

> **https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2548#section-2.4.2**

===========================[image]==========================

Wireshark traces of Access Accept showing Key transfer to Authenticator.